# Adding two date time objects when the line matches from a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, time, strip

I have a list which consist of data like

```
data1_part1 data1_part2 -> 1:02:04
data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 0:01:01
data3_part1 data3_part3 -> 1:01:02
data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 1:02:01
```

In this case I want the output as

```
data1_part1 data1_part2 -> 1:02:04
data3_part1 data3_part3 -> 1:01:02
data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 1:03:02
```

Adding up the time if the data part is already found in the list, or else printing it as it is.

*Code till now:*

```
value_len = len(value_list)
searched_val = []

for x in range(0,value_len):

    val = value_list[x].split(" -> ")[0]
    time_1 = value_list[x].split(" -> ")[1]

    time_val = datetime.strptime(time_1, "%H:%M:%S")
    #time_val = time_val.time()

    if str(val) in searched_val:
        for z in range(0,len(searched_val)):
            print ("search val: " + str(searched_val[z]))
            time_old = str(searched_val[z].split(" -> ")[1])
            time_old = time_old.split()[1]

            hr = int(time_old.split(":")[0])
            mins = int(time_old.split(":")[1])
            sec = int(time_old.split(":")[2])

            del_time = timedelta(hours=hr,minutes=mins,seconds=sec)
            time = time_val + del_time

            searched_val.append(str(val) + " -> " + str(time))
    else:
        searched_val.append(str(val) + " -> " + str(time_val))
        #print (len(search_val))

for x in range(0, len(searched_val)):
        print ("Added time: " + str(searched_val[x]))
```

But this does not print the answer I was expecting as I find that the execution does not go into the

```
for z in range(0,len(searched_val)):
```

As I guess the string values at the first part (i.e) before `"->"` could not be matched. I don't really know why though.

Comment: how about printing both `val` and `searched_val` and checking which values are there?

Comment: @Ashalynd  I tried the issue is `if str(val) in searched_val:` could not find the sub string `val` in `searched_val`. The final print statement prints everything which was there in the input, which means that the statement did not get into the `for z in range(0,len(searched_val)):` and the time is not added up.

Comment: Does the order in which the `data_x part_y` lines appear matter? If not, you'd be far easier off by using dictionaries.

Comment: @OliverW. The order does not matter only the time should be added. Can you please give me an example how to implement it in another way

Comment: @user3703782 I've given you an example and explained why your code doesn't work. Was the answer not clear? If you need more clarifications, you could ask for them in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work, is because you never actually update the element in `searched_val`, which in turn is because your `if` check fails: you are checking for a substring of the strings in a list. That doesn't work:

```
>>> l = ['hello 11', 'world 22']
>>> 'hello' in l  # substring in list?
False
>>> 'hello 11' in l  # full element in list?
True
```

One solution that is more pythonic is given below. It uses dictionaries. Note that I'm using a `defaultdict` from the [collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), which I felt was more useful here.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> # First, generate a list of strings, similar to yours
... U = """data1_part1 data1_part2 -> 1:02:04
... data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 0:01:01
... data3_part1 data3_part3 -> 1:01:02
... data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 1:02:01""".split('\n')  
>>> 
>>> unix_epoch = datetime(1900,1,1)
>>> coll = defaultdict(lambda: unix_epoch)
>>> for row in U:
...     key, timing = row.split(' -> ')
...     coll[key] += (datetime.strptime(timing, "%H:%M:%S") - unix_epoch)
... 
>>> for k,v in coll.items():
...     print("{} -> {}".format(k, v.strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
... 
data2_part1 data2_part2 -> 01:03:02
data1_part1 data1_part2 -> 01:02:04
data3_part1 data3_part3 -> 01:01:02
```

It is important to realize that this code (or rather the interpretation of its results) is subject to timing overflows: when you sum up 2 hours to some item that already has a timing indication of `23h`, the code will correctly jump to the next day, but will only show `01` hours. From my own experience, I can only recommend changing timestamps to full timing indications (=date+time) as early as possible.